# How to get closest number out of list in elixir

Tags: elixir

How to get closest number out of a list?

Test:

```
test do "check closest number" do
 assert closest_number([1,100,250,800,1300], 78) == 100
end
```

Comment: What should the results be for `closest_number([1,4], 3)`? What about `closest_number([1,3], 2)`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Enum.min_by` with a function that calculates the absolute difference of the numbers in the list and `78`:

```
iex(1)> Enum.min_by([1, 100, 250, 800, 1300], &abs(&1 - 78))
100
```